# launch file for rxbag

Tags: ros, roslaunch, rxbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I want to launch rxbag from a launch file and load the appropiate data directly.
is that possible? I've been looking but I found no examples or anything about launching rxbag from a launchfile.

Cheers!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32292/launch-file-for-rxbag/) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2012-04-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
<node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="play" args="--bag /path/to/your/filename.bag --rate 0.5"  />
```

---

Originally posted by [Yogi](https://answers.ros.org/users/105/yogi/) with karma: 411 on 2012-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
<launch>
  <node name="rxbag_1" pkg="rxbag" type="rxbag" args="foo.bag"/>
</launch>
```

Although working, this throws a few exceptions because rxbag doesn't seem to ignore ros command line parameters such as __name and __log although it should...

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-04-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yogi](https://answers.ros.org/users/105/yogi/) on 2012-04-21**:
This is bad because rxbag is the gui program responsible for visualizing bag files, and you are asking it to play the bag. That would probbaly explain all the exceotions you are getting. Better/correct way is to just use the play node in the rosbag package, as shown in answer.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-04-21**:
The question was explicitly asking for rxbag and there are already plenty of examples showing how to use rosbag in roslaunch so my answer is correct. Btw it is not totally uncommon to start gui apps from roslaunch. See rviz.